# Is there any way to add Office Assistant character to Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

Is there any way to add office assistant character to Office 2010? I miss my cat office assistant, it was cute and made my day.

[image]

Comment: http://www.rjlpranks.com/pranks/clippy/

Comment: SO YOU'RE THE ONE

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully (for me, but perhaps not you), the answer is 'no'.

Microsoft completely removed the Office Assistant from Office 2007 and future versions.

See [here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-happened-to-the-office-assistant-HA010047975.aspx) for their own description:

> The online Help feature in the 2007 Microsoft Office system has been completely redesigned, and the new design does not include the Microsoft Office Assistant.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sathya - I'd seen the page before, but misread it as being 2010+ (must have been asleep this morning!)